# create interface object in mxml

Tags: apache-flex, flash, mxml

Let's say I have an interface

```
public interface IFoo {
   ...
}
```

and I have several implementing classes

```
public class Foo implements IFoo {
    ...
}

...

public class Bar implements IFoo {
    ...
}

...

public class Baz implements IFoo {
    ...
}
```

I want to reference IFoo in MXML like this

```
<ns:IFoo id="myfoo"/>
```

and have it be instantiated at runtime by a factory.

However, the compiler won't let me do this-- it's trying to do "new IFoo" in the generated ActionScript.

How to get around this?  How can I use an interface and a factory purely in MXML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring an MXML child instantiates an object of that type - you can't simply declare a property in MXML without associating an instance with it.

Given that - there's no way to achieve the equivalent of

```
public var myFoo:IFoo;
```

in your MXML.

As James pointed out, you can use a ClassFactory to acheive the following:

```
<mx:ClassFactory class="{Foo}" id="fooFactory" />
```

but you would be required to call `fooFactory.newInstance()` to get an `IFoo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement interfaces in MXML components with the `implements="IFoo"` attribute in the component's root node.

**Edit:**

Sorry, I missunderstood your question. I don't know a way to implement a factory in pure mxml. I guess you have to use Actionscript or mxml states to achieve a similar behaviour.

Comment: I don't want to create a component that implements an interface.  I want to *instantiate* a component that implements an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ClassFactory](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/ClassFactory.html?allClasses=1).  It is how things like item renderers are instantiated.